# How to set AWS VPN bandwith rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hello we have a VPN connection set up and an EC2 instance. Is it possible to limit the throughput of traffic from the instance over the VPN?

Thank you!

Comment: No that I'm aware of - it's not mentioned in any documentation I've read. Perhaps the customer gateway router can do that, or can you rate limit on your EC2 instance? You might also be able to set up an EC2 instance with custom software to terminate your VPN that would do it, but using managed services is generally preferred. Why do you want to limit throughput?

Comment: Hi, to throttle the uplink usage for a transfer. It is most likely doable on the customer gateway device but I assumed AWS would have some means of limiting throughput. I did it on the OS level now with tc.

Comment: To help others, please write an answer with bit more detail of how you achieved this.